# Internet Options window does not open

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, internet-security

On a windows Server 2008R2 - while logged as the domain administrator.

I am unable to open the `Internet Options` windows.

[image]

Using the IE Tools: I get a restrictions error:

```
Restrictions
This operation has been cancelled due to restrictions in effect on this computer. Please contact your system administrator.
```

[image]

- Other servers work fine.
- Firefox works fine on the server - IE doesn't.
- I ran the [Microsoft Safety Scanner](http://www.microsoft.com/security/scanner/en-us/default.aspx) Quick scan - Nothing found or fixed
- IE About - is greyed out.

[image]

- Behaviour is isolated to this certain server only.
- Other users, logged - get the same behaviour.
- Control panel is not working either

[image]

- `inetcpl.cpl` - not working
- `gpresult` is not showing me something out of the ordinary - I don't think it's a GPo setting

> C:\Users\realadmin>gpresult -r
>
> Microsoft (R) Windows (R) Operating System Group Policy Result tool
>   v2.0 Copyright (C) Microsoft Corp. 1981-2001
>
> Created On 7/17/2013 at 1:49:21 PM
>
> ### RSOP data for company\realadmin on BOROMIR : Logging Mode
>
> OS Configuration:            Member Server OS Version:
>   6.1.7600 Site Name:                   Default-First-Site-Name Roaming Profile:             N/A Local Profile:
>   C:\Users\realadmin Connected over a slow link?: No
>
> ### COMPUTER SETTINGS
>
> ```
> CN=BOROMIR,OU=Servers,OU=company Computers,DC=company
> Last time Group Policy was applied: 7/17/2013 at 12:17:19 PM
> Group Policy was applied from:      DC2.company
> Group Policy slow link threshold:   500 kbps
> Domain Name:                        company
> Domain Type:                        Windows 2000
>
> Applied Group Policy Objects
> -----------------------------
>     Default Domain Policy
>     Firewall - Disabled
>     SOPHOS Tasks Enabler
>     Logon - Enable Verbose State
>     Remove UAC
>     Default Servers
>     WSUS - DownloadOnly
>     Local Group Policy
>
> The computer is a part of the following security groups
> -------------------------------------------------------
>     BUILTIN\Administrators
>     Everyone
>     BUILTIN\Users
>     NT AUTHORITY\NETWORK
>     NT AUTHORITY\Authenticated Users
>     This Organization
>     BOROMIR$
>     Domain Computers
>     System Mandatory Level
> ```
>
> ### USER SETTINGS
>
> ```
> CN=realadmin,CN=Users,DC=company
> Last time Group Policy was applied: 7/17/2013 at 1:45:25 PM
> Group Policy was applied from:      DC2.company
> Group Policy slow link threshold:   500 kbps
> Domain Name:                        company
> Domain Type:                        Windows 2000
>
> Applied Group Policy Objects
> -----------------------------
>     Default Domain Policy
>     Drive Mappings
>     Local Group Policy
>
> The following GPOs were not applied because they were filtered out
> -------------------------------------------------------------------
>     Firewall - Disabled
>         Filtering:  Not Applied (Empty)
>
> The user is a part of the following security groups
> ---------------------------------------------------
>     Domain Users
>     Everyone
>     BUILTIN\Users
>     BUILTIN\Administrators
>     REMOTE INTERACTIVE LOGON
>     NT AUTHORITY\INTERACTIVE
>     NT AUTHORITY\Authenticated Users
>     This Organization
>     LOCAL
>     company_dev
>     AB_admins
>     SALES_DEP
>     Domain Admins
>     Group Policy Creator Owners
>     MNG_DEP
>     Enterprise Admins
>     Schema Admins
>     SophosAdministrator
>     Denied RODC Password Replication Group
>     High Mandatory Level C:\Users\realadmin>
> ```

Comment: There a reason your using IE8 instead of say IE9 or IE10?  Are you an `Administrator` on the domain?  Being a local Administrator doesn't mean jack when dealing with windows domains.

Comment: @Ramhound weird or not, but you nailed it. I didn't even noticed that. I installed IE9 (10 is not working on 2008R2) and all works fine now. post this as an accepted answer.

Comment: You can answer your own question if you want.  I was just trying to get a internet connected computer on a safe version of IE.  What likely happen is there was some registry key corrupt, and the installation, reset the configuration of IE in general.  The next ting I was going ot suggest is to remove the user from some of those groups, just to verify, it wasn't actually a permission problem.

Answer (score 0):

After installing IE9 - things start to work.

Something might have been corrupted, and re-installing IE9 must have fixed the issue.